# HttpRoutingDispatcher and How can we register in web api pipe line

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Currently I am looking at Detail Pipeline of WebAPI. I am getting bit confuse of HttpRoutingDispatcher.

As we can create our own class that inherit from HttpRoutingDispatcher then How can we use that or register that ?

What is exact use of HttpRoutingDispatcher ?

Comment: Did you get answer to this question? I also wanted to understand the exact use of HttpRoutingDispatcher.

Answer (score 0):

You can register it by setting GlobalConfiguration.DefaultHandler property.
The purpose of this class is to parse route arguments(like id) and to fill them to HttpRequestMessage.